# BeautifulSoup не парсит Facebook

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, beautiful-soup, lxml

```
r = requests.get('https://www.facebook.com/170515954946/posts/10154608790824947/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

pos = r.text.find('Давайте отметим этот день все вместе')
r.text[pos - 100: pos + 200]
```

Тут мы увидим следующий output, по которому можно сделать вывод, что текст поста прогрузился

```
s/10154608790824947/"><span class="fcg">4 февраля 2016г.</span></a></div> 
<div class="_6nm"><div><p>Давайте отметим этот
день все вместе – расскажите о ваших друзьях, которые меняют вас,
делают вас лу
```

Получается, что текст поста можно получить с помощью

```
soup.find('div', class_='_6nm')
```

Но в ответ мы получим `None`.

Возникает вопрос, почему?

P.s. вместо `lxml` пробовал `html5lib` и `html.parser` - они возвращают тот же `None`

P.s.s нашел решение, представлено ниже

Comment: потому что этот текст находится в `<script> ... </script>`

Comment: @MaxU, оу... я понял. А как бы вы порекомендовали поступить в этой ситуации?

Answer (score 0):

Заметим, что код во всех скриптах - это правильный html, поэтому напишем свой простенький парсер, работа которого основана на задаче о нахождении правильной скобочной последовательности:) Когда мы нашли правильную скобочную последовательность, скопируем ее от начальной до конечной скобки. И так далее.